# Interpretation of the graph of accelerometer

Tags: accelerometer, freescale

I have plotted the raw values of my accelerometer in gnuplot,
and the acceleration in the dimensions of x, y and z are as follows...

[image]

The accelerometer sensor is in a steady position, my question is.

**Why the values of Z are always in 1.**

Comment: Check the scaling on the graph. If the units are g, this is OK as in @kvegaoro's answer. But if they are m/s^2, you should see 9.8, not 1.

Answer (score 4):

Check the orientation of your accelerometer because what the graph is saying is that your accelerometer is position in such a way that your Z-axis is parallel to direction of gravitiy. In other words that fact that your z axis is always around just means that your are measuring the acceleration due to gravity caused by Earth.

Comment: So, the 1 value is because of the gravitation of the earth 1.81.. something.

Comment: No, the gravitation at the earth's surface is 9.81 m/sec^2. The scale factor for your accelerometers is probably 10 m/sec^2 per volt - regardless of how you've labeled your plot. And either your unit is sitting at a slight angle, or your accelerometer has considerable offsets. (Which would explain why your z axis is slightly more than 1, as well.)